# Does initializing references cost more memory if you copy to an lvalue less than the size of a reference?

Tags: c++

So I believe on 64-bit systems a pointer is 8B.  A float is 4B.  Let's say you have the following code:

```
const float a = 1.0f;
```

Then, I want to know the cost comparison of the following.  Say we have

```
const float b = a;
```

I know that copying `float` will be 4B.  But I would think that we can 'save' memory if we don't have to copy the `float`.  I know that if it weren't `float`, but instead a large object (>8B), using a reference in a similar manner would be more optimal:

```
const float &b = a;
```

However, since we are using float, is it more compact to copy to a new variable?  Assuming that the compiler won't optimize anything?

```
const float a = b;
const float &a = b;
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing references with pointers. A reference is not an object and has no size.

Comment: Well, really, I was confused about whether a reference had any cost during runtime.  I'm not trying to argue, but I reckoned that it would have to have some cost to use a reference.  If a reference is not an object and it has no size, then how does the CPU find the variable?  I thought that the reference would have no size but still have to locate the object using its address (as the address would be 8B), and therefore I am comparing that operation with setting a new float.  I remember hearing somewhere that reference behavior can be emulated with pointers and cost exactly the same.

Comment: But again, I have also read many times that a reference is not an object and has no size, so I'm confused in a way because then it must objectively be more efficient to use references wherever possible, even when the cost of a new object is less than that of referring to the original object (by its address, which is not stored as it is a reference, but it used by the CPU)

Comment: I find stuff like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641907/do-variable-references-alias-incure-runtime-cost
"It may be treated as an alias, but not in terms of efficiency. Underneath the hood, a reference is a pointer with a nicer syntax and higher safety guarantees. Hence you've got a "dereference" operation runtime penalty. UNLESS the compiler optimizes it, but I wouldn't count on that usually."

Comment: Technically there is no cost for a reference, it is merely assigning a new name to an existing variable, but some uses of a reference will be silently implemented with a pointer behind the scenes.

Comment: It really depends on implementation details of your compiler, but there is nothing preventing an implementation from eliminating all `const` variables from memory entirely, and directly substituting the actual value in every place where the name of that `const` is used. Similarly, there is often nothing requiring a compiler to store references in memory - the compiler routinely keeps track so knows using a reference is the same as using the object it refers to.  Most modern compilers, with even basic optimisation settings, will eliminate `b` (and probably also `a`) entirely from emitted code.

Comment: *"Assuming that the compiler won't optimize anything?"* -- this seems like an odd assumption for a question about optimal code.

Comment: Both `const float a = b;` and `const float &a = b;` have no observable behavior by themselves. A compiler will likely generate no relevant machine code, unless there is some subsequent code that uses `a`. But then, the machine code will depend on that subsequent source code. The question does not make much sense without such code.

Comment: _"...References are not objects; they do not necessarily occupy storage, although the compiler __may__ allocate storage if it is necessary to implement the desired semantics ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference .  See also [Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `const float b = a;` then you are making a copy of the value. Now if the type is a fundamental type or trivially copyable with no custom copy constructor the compiler can easily optimize away the copy and no actual code gets generated at all. That is unless you take the address of the obejct:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const float a = 1.0;
    const float b = a;
    const float &r = a;
    std::cout << "&a == &b: " << (&a == &b ? "true" : "false") << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "&a == &r: " << (&a == &r ? "true" : "false") << std::endl; 
}
```

gives:

```
&a == &b: false
&a == &r: true
```

As you can see `a` and `b` have different addresses. They are different objects and the compiler will have to add a copy of `a` named `b`. The reference `r` on the other hand is the same object as `a` so it has the same address. The compiler will not make a copy.

This also holds if `a` isn't a trivial type and the compiler can't eliminate the copy constructor. The reference is a total NOP, it just gives the existing object another name.

---

But don't confuse this with passing values by reference or storing references in structs or classes. Internally a reference is implemented as a pointer. If you pass a reference then you pass a copy of the pointer. If you store a reference then the pointer is stored.

Only for local references the compiler can use the original object directly.

Comment: And then the optimizer gets involved.

Comment: Hmm, I now wonder: If you have a totally simplistic c++ compiler might it not implement local references as pointers as well? Then `float &r = a;` would create a local variable pointing at a. Not sure why you would want that but it would be standard conform I think. So a `float&` might use 8 bytes in a very specific case of an odd compiler.